# Pytorch/numpy/python efficient Interpolation of corrupted data

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have temporal discrete information which may have missing values.
I do have a mask indicating where are those values too.

How can I perform an efficient interpolation filling those values?

In practice I have a `TxCxJ` tensor (**Q**). Some elements are let’s say corrupted. I would like, given a corrupted element `Q[t,c,j]`, to fill that value with an interpolation between `Q[t-1,c,j]` and `Q[t+1,c,j]`

Also, in the worst case I may find several consecutive corrupted elements:
`Q[t_0:t_1,c,j]`

to be filled with the interpolation between
`Q[t_0-1,c,j]` and `Q[t_1+1,c,j]`

It is ok to use linear interpolation using numpy or pytorch (or any other suitable libray for which I don't need to study 5 months :/). I can code it using for loops but i was looking for any efficient library which allows to pass a mask or something with some sort of cool indexing/masking not having to run the algorithm for known points.

Thaaanks

Comment: When you post a problem in SO, it's encourage to describe what have you tried and expected output

Comment: This is a custom procedure for which I wouldn't expect an "easy" solution or lib.

Comment: Hi, In the end it's just interpolating but instead of increasing the size of the tensor filling values given a mask. I don't think it is such an strange case

Comment: Are there missing values on the border also? eg. Q[0,c,j] is corrupted. Here you have to define how to extrapolate a value. How do you define corrupted (eg NaN or something else)?